# query de mysql con tkinter DateEntry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

tengo un problema con el nuevo tkinter bootstrap, sus DateEntry no tienen la opción **"get_date()"** que coloca la fecha en un formato para mysql. Intenté cambiarlo colocando el formato en **".configure(dateformat="%Y-%m-%d")"** pero los guiones siguen apareciendo cómo diagonales cuando hago el query: **"28/12/2022"**.
Por lo que la terminal arroja:

> mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1525 (HY000): Incorrect DATE
> value: '22/12/2022'

Aquí dejo el código completo para que puedan reproducir el problema, si alguien me puede ayudar, muchas gracias. Agrego, He consultado las documentaciones en github, readthedocs y en su página oficial, no he encontrado nada que pueda ayudarme con este problema.

```
import tkinter as tk
import ttkbootstrap as ttkb
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *
from time import strftime
import mysql.connector

ventana_reporte_fechas=tk.Tk()
ventana_reporte_fechas.geometry("700x500")
ventana_reporte_fechas.title("Reportes por Fechas")

f_desde=ttkb.DateEntry(ventana_reporte_fechas, dateformat="%d/%m/%Y")
f_desde.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=5, pady=5)

def exportar_excell():
    f_desde.configure(dateformat="%Y-%m-%d")
    fecha_query1=f_desde.entry.get()
    
    conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
    cursor1=conn.cursor()
    ticket=cursor1.execute('''SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE Fecha='{0}' '''.format(fecha_query1))
    cursor1.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    
    print(ticket)
    


boton_exportar=ttkb.Button(ventana_reporte_fechas, text="Exportar a Excell", command=exportar_excell)
boton_exportar.grid(column=2, row=5, padx=5, pady=5)

ventana_reporte_fechas.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La documentación de [DateEntry](https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/widgets/dateentry/) no me es tan clara, pero pareciera que el `.configure()` esta ignorando el nuevo formato, porque al parecer no funciona de esa manera.

Sin embargo, podrías convertirlo manualmente:

```py
fentry1 = f_desde.entry.get()
fecha_query1 = '{}-{}-{}'.format(fentry1[6:], fentry1[3:5], fentry1[:2])
```

O también puedes usar el módulo datetime:

```py
import datetime
# ...
fentry1 = f_desde.entry.get()
fecha_query1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(fentry1, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Gracias @aeportugal, usé la segunda opció y me corrió